# MySQL db Audit Trail Trigger

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, audit-trail

I need to track changes (audit trail) in certain tables in a MySql Db.  I am trying to implement the solution suggested [here](http://www.symbiosoft.net/?q=mysql+single+table+audit+trail).

I have an AuditLog Table with the following columns: AuditLogID, TableName, RowPK, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, TimeStamp.

The mysql stored procedure is the following (this executes fine, and creates the procedure):

The call to the procedure such as: CALL addLogTrigger('ProductTypes', 'ProductTypeID');
executes, but does not create any triggers (see the image).  SHOW TRIGGERS returns empty set.

Please let me know what could be the issue, or an alternate way to implement this.

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addLogTrigger;
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE addLogTrigger(IN tableName VARCHAR(255), IN pkField VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    SELECT CONCAT(
    'DELIMITER $\n', 'CREATE TRIGGER ', tableName, '_AU AFTER UPDATE ON ', tableName, ' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
          'IF NOT( OLD.', column_name, ' <=> NEW.', column_name, ') THEN INSERT INTO AuditLog (',
                    'TableName, ',
                    'RowPK, ',
                    'FieldName, ',
                    'OldValue, ',
                    'NewValue'
                    ') VALUES ( ''',
                    table_name, ''', NEW.',
                    pkField, ', ''',
                    column_name, ''', OLD.',
                    column_name, ', NEW.',
                    column_name,
                '); END IF;'
            )
            SEPARATOR ' '
            ), ' END;$'
        ) 
        FROM 
            information_schema.columns 
        WHERE 
            table_schema = database()
            AND table_name = tableName;

END$
DELIMITER ;
```

[alt text http://pssnet.com/~devone/pssops3/testing/callprocedure.png](http://pssnet.com/~devone/pssops3/testing/callprocedure.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find this stored procedure doesn't create the triggers; it creates SQL statements to create the triggers. Squirt the output from this procedure into a file somewhere and then run it.

Looking at the output there appear to be some spurious vertical bar characters in it that could give trouble; my eyesight isn't what it might be so I can't be sure.